# How can I get my classroom id / student id

Tags: python, google-classroom

I'm trying to create a program that gets all the students in a classroom and then checks each student indivually if the last assignment have been submitted or not but I always seem to get that the class id is wrong ( I got it using HTML inspect since it's not visible on google classroom itself ).

This is the code :

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
import google.oauth2.service_account

# Set the path to the JSON key file
JSON_KEY_FILE_PATH = 'E:\Computer Science A2\Past Papers P4\Variant 2\pythonProject/followup-system-400422-a994cd3df2c6.json'

# Create a Google Classroom API service object
credentials = google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(JSON_KEY_FILE_PATH)
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# Get the students list
students = service.courses().students().list(courseId='626604275712').execute()['students']

# Get the last assignment
assignments = service.courses().courseWork().list(courseId='626604275712').execute()['courseWork']
last_assignment = assignments[0]

# Check if student X submitted code
student_x_submission = service.courses().courseWork().studentSubmissions().get(courseId='626604275712', courseWorkId=last_assignment['id'], userId='626603760934').execute()

if student_x_submission['status'] == 'TURNED_IN':
    print('Student X submitted code for the last assignment.')
else:
    print('Student X did not submit code for the last assignment.')
```

but I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Computer Science A2\Past Papers P4\Variant 2\pythonProject\main2.py", line 12, in <module>
    students = service.courses().students().list(courseId='626604275712').execute()['students']
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Computer Science A2\Past Papers P4\Variant 2\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Computer Science A2\Past Papers P4\Variant 2\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 935, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/626604275712/students?alt=json returned "Requested entity was not found.". Details: "Requested entity was not found.">
```

is there a way to get google classroom course id?

Comment: Try to get the list of courses and see if the id matches the one you are using: https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/blob/main/classroom/snippets/classroom_list_courses.py